# /etc/hosts and aliases

Tags: hostname, hosts

I puchased a domain, say `fireworks.com`, and I would like to call my server `ubuntu-18-04`. 
 How am I expected to edit `/etc/hosts`?
Is it possible to add multiple aliases as follows?

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ubuntu-18-04.fireworks.com fireworks.com ubuntu-18-04
5.247.221.66 ubuntu-18-04.fireworks.com fireworks.com ubuntu-18-04
```

Usually in documentation the /etc/hosts format has only three records:

```
1. An IP address
2. A fqdn
3. The hostname
```

Is it possible (and necessary?) to add a fourth record, as in my previous example, including `fireworks.com`? I would like to receive mail as `sam@fireworks.com` other than as `sam@ubuntu-18-04.fireworks.com`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `man hosts`:

> This manual page describes the format of the /etc/hosts file.  This
>          file is a simple text file that associates IP addresses with
>          hostnames, one line per IP address.  For each host a single line
>          should be present with the following information:
>
> ```
>           IP_address canonical_hostname [aliases...]
> ```

Yes, you can add multiple lines of IPs and aliases. But for your mail reception, I'd suggest you use DNS for domain name mapping. Use `dnsmasq` to make it easier, it resolves from `/etc/hosts` too